# From HTML to .pdf - in a recorsive way

Tags: pdf, html

I read some (old) treads about this matter,
but I've to create a .pdf of a whole part of a site.

I was able to download all this with wget -r.

Then, I tried to use wkhtmltopdf,
but it seems to me that it doesn't support an -r option,
or something similar to operate in a recorsive way.

Is there another way?

Thank you

Comment: Read `man wkhtmltopdf`, the whole thing.

Comment: I don't understand. A PDF is paper-page oriented. You can't represent a whole graph of websites in one PDF sensibly.

Comment: Sounds like the early attempts to print Wikipedia for non-Internet connected users

Comment: From man pages: "This version of wkhtmltopdf has been compiled against a version of QT without   the wkhtmltopdf patches. Therefore some features are missing". So, do I need the static version, not present in Debian repository?

Comment: @waltinator I have a similar issue and also don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting that wkhtmltopdf is able to convert a collection of html files into a single pdf documents, like the OP requested? Would you mind giving us the relevant command line option, as I can't find it in the man page?